# Google Signin Delegate method not found in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, integration, google-signin

want to implement the googleSign integration in form.When I trying to get the GISDelegate method in appDelegate file there is no method available so how i can get this method in swift.
[image]

Comment: You sure this isn´t just a typo? Shouldn´t this be 'GIDSignInDelegate'?

Comment: But still GIDSignInDelegate not available see the screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Muhammad Abdul Faheem,

Try to update podfile by command pod update and delete derived data by following these steps:

1.Open your project,Go to files -> Workspace Settings

Then you will find a derived data location with an arrow:-

Just click on that arrow,after that you will find a folder named derived data, delete all the files inside derived data folder. Then it will working fine.

[image: Check Screenshot here]

Comment: GIDSignInDelegate used but no delegate available.